# Multiple references in limecv

Tags: cv

I am trying to write a resume using limecv. I want to include three persons in references section. The following is a part of tex file that I have:

```
\begin{cvReferences}
    \footnotesize
  \cvAddReference{%
    name=Person1,
    company=Company ABC Co.\ Ltd.,
    position=Job title,
    address line 1=Street lane 2,
    address line 2=Address1,
    mobile phone=123456789}%
\cvAddReference{%
    name=Person2,
    company=Company ABC Co.\ Ltd.,
    position=Job title,
    address line 1=Street lane 2,
    address line 2=Address2,
    mobile phone=123456789}%

\cvAddReference{%
name=Person3,
company=Company ABC Co.\ Ltd.,
position=Job title,
address line 1=Street lane 2,
address line 2=Address3,
mobile phone=123456789}%

\end{cvReferences}
```

The result is shown in the picture below:[image]

As seen in the picture the third reference is cut out of the document. I was thinking of reducing the spacing between the references so that I can accomodate the third reference in the document. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you try tabularx to see if it can give you what you want?